# android RealmMigrationNeededException update from 0.87 to 1.0.0

Tags: android, realm

I use the version 0.8.7 in my app and it works fine. But I want to update the version to 1.0.0. Then I got the error when I test update from old version of my app to the new one with the realm version 1.0.0.
So I searched online and know I should use migration but how to use it. Because I didn't change my object. I just update the realm version. What should I do.

Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided

Answer (score 1):

RealmMigrationNeededException happen after change on database like SQLite
try to uninstall your app and install again

Answer (score 1):

Primary keys became nullable, so you'll have to either migrate them to be nullable, or add `@Required` field on top of your primary keys.

```
0.89.0

Breaking changes

@PrimaryKey field value can now be null for 
    String, Byte, Short, Integer, and Long types. 
Older Realms should be migrated, using RealmObjectSchema.setNullable(), 
    or by adding the @Required annotation. (#2515).
```

More info at [#2515](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2515) and [the change log](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).